# Redirect Base + Short Url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-shortener

I am trying to do a simple custom url shortner .

I have this domain "a.st" that I need to redirect to: "astrit.co"

How can I create a redirect "a.st/234" >> "astrit.co/?p=234"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} a\.st [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://astrit.co/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.st$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(234) http://astrit.co/?p=$1 [L,R]
```